# Create a JSON/text file based on contents of a csv file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to loop through a csv file (approximately 91 million records) and create a new json/text file using a Python `dict` based on the sample records below (File is sorted on id,type).

```
id,type,value
4678367,1,1001
4678367,2,1007
4678367,2,1008
5678945,1,9000
5678945,2,8000
```

The code should append values when it matches id and type else create a new record as below. I would like to write this to a target file

How can I do this in Python?

```
{'id':4678367,
 'id_1':[1001],
 'id_2':[1007,1008]
},
{'id':5678945,
 'id_1':[9000],
 'id_2':[8000]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to collect the items.  I have left the writing to a file as an exercise:

#### Code:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    columns = next(reader)
    results = []
    record = {}
    current_type = 0
    items = []
    for id_, type, value in reader:
        if current_type != type:
            if current_type:
                record['id_{}'.format(current_type)] = items
                items = []
            current_type = type

        if id_ != record.get('id'):
            if record:
                results.append(record)
            record = dict(id=id_)

        items.append(value)

    if record:
        record['id_{}'.format(current_type)] = items
        results.append(record)

print(results)
```

#### Results:

```
[
    {'id': '4678367', 'id_1': ['1001'], 'id_2': ['1007', '1008']}, 
    {'id': '5678945', 'id_1': ['9000'], 'id_2': ['8000']}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple

with open("data.csv","r") as f:
    read = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(read)
    col = namedtuple('col',header)
    dictionary = {}
    for values in read:
        data = col(*values)
        type_ = 'id_' + str(data.type)
        if data.id in dictionary:
            local_dict = dictionary[data.id]                
            if type_ in local_dict:
                local_dict[type_].append(data.value)
            else:
                local_dict[type_] = [data.value]
        else:
            dictionary.setdefault(data.id,{'id':data.id,type_:[data.value]})
print(*dictionary.values(),sep="\n")
>>>{'id': '4678367', 'id_1': ['1001'], 'id_2': ['1007', '1008']}
   {'id': '5678945', 'id_1': ['9000'], 'id_2': ['8000']}
```